# In Laravel, should I check for permission in controller if already checking on middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization, laravel-middleware

I created a middleware that checks if the user is authorized to perform an action and added this middleware to the routes that I want to protect like this:

```
// VerifyPermission middleware

class VerifyPermission {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @param $permission
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        if (auth()->check() && $user->hasPermission($permission))
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}

// Routes

Route::patch('company/{id}', ['as' => 'updateCompany',
                              'uses' => 'SettingsController@updateCompany',
                              'middleware' => 'permission:manage_company']
);
```

My question is, is it necessary to make another check on `updateCompany` or is the middleware check sufficient?

```
public function updateCompany()
{
    if(Auth::user()->hasPermission('manage_company'))
    {
        // Updates Company
    }   

    return abort(403, "Unauthorized");
}
```

Comment: The controller action will be executed after the middleware. So its not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should not make another check, the middleware will do it.

In fact handling authentication and permission handling is one of the most frequent uses for middleware

when you specify this:

```
Route::patch('company/{id}', ['as' => 'updateCompany',
                          'uses' => 'SettingsController@updateCompany',
                          'middleware' => 'permission:manage_company']
```

You're telling laravel that, when it finds a `company/{id}` route, it should trigger the `handle` method of the `permission:manage_company` middleware, **before** the request is sent to the `SettingsController`

So, when the request will get to your controller you're sure that it has satisfied all the middleware it went through